Default method vs concrete method in abstract class?
After Java 8, if we have default method in interface and concrete method in abstract class, then what is the significance of default method in interface over concrete method of abstract class?
I thought that default methods are used for common functionality and concrete methods in abstract class have their own functionality.
But, I am not sure about the exact picture regarding both the methods.
